# How do I calculate the Time Complexity of a polynomial within a square root?

Tags: polynomials, computational-complexity

So say I have the following polynomial $F(n)=\sqrt{5n^2+7n-13}$ and I want to calculate it's upper and lower bounds ($O(n)$ and $\Omega(n)$), as well as the overall complexity $\Theta(n)$. What is the general process for doing so if there is a square root? I know for a normal polynomial I am proving for example $f=O(g)$ & $f=\Omega(g)$ by using the $c$ and setting $n_0 = 1$ in order to prove the inequalities. However when it comes down to having a square root, I'm at a loss of where/how to start. My initial thoughts are I have to use $g(n)=\sqrt(n^2)$ but at second look that doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\sqrt{5n^2+7n-13}=\sqrt{5}n\sqrt{1+\frac{7}{5n}-\frac{13}{5n^2}}$ and that $\lim\sqrt{1+\frac{7}{5n}-\frac{13}{5n^2}}=1$ as $n\to\infty$, so asymptotically the function grows as $\sqrt{5}n$.

Comment: That clears some stuff up, but how do I use this in a formal "proof". Like normally I would show that for any $n \ge 1$ that $f(n) \leq c * g(n)$. How do I pick my $c$ and $g(n)$ in this case?

Comment: @Rietty You already have your $g$. That's $\sqrt5n$. As for $c$, you just have to study that other factor and see what values it takes.

Comment: @Arthur Gotcha, so normally I would add up the coefficients in order to get my `c`, can I do the same thing here and do `5 + 7 - 13` to get `-1`? Or is there some other thing to do.

Comment: @Rietty We now know that $f(x) = \sqrt5n\cdot \sqrt{1 + \frac{7}{5n} - \frac{13}{5n^2}}$. If we take the $g$ from my previous comment, that leaves $\sqrt{1 + \frac{7}{5n} - \frac{13}{5n^2}}$. We want
$$
\sqrt5n\cdot \sqrt{1 + \frac{7}{5n} - \frac{13}{5n^2}}\leq \sqrt5n\cdot c
$$
So you have to study the values that $\sqrt{1 + \frac{7}{5n} - \frac{13}{5n^2}}$ takes for different values of $n$ in order to see what $c$ you should choose.

Comment: @Arthur That clears it up immensely! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, when $n$ is very large the first term dominates over the other two, so $F(n)\approx \sqrt{5n^2}=n\sqrt 5$.  We don't care about multiplicative constants, so $F(n) \in \Theta(n)$.  You can make this more precise if you want by dividing the $n$ out of the square root and seeing that the other terms have factors of $\frac 1n$